# How to construct the URL for search with multiple input?

Tags: seo, url, canonical-url, url-parameters

I am having a home page where I can search on multiple tags. How should I construct the URL?
Suppose I search for `tag = test_1` and `tag = test_2`

Should I construct the url like

```
http://www.example.com/tag/test-1,test-2
```

or

```
http://www.example.com/tag/?tag=test-1,test-2
```

or

```
www.example.com/tag/test-1-test-2
```

or

any other option?

I know query params are generally ignored by search engines and I should not put comma in URL so according to it "`www.example.com/tag/test-1-test-2`" is best option but I am afraid that **`www.example.com/tag/test-1-test-2`** and **`www.example.com/tag/test-2-test-1`** will generate the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My view would be that it doesn't matter for SEO because I'd be noindexing these pages anyway. Google doesn't want to index your search results in its search results, and it's a great way to get flagged for duplicate content.

Concentrate on SEO for the actual content pages and do whatever's best for the user experience for these kinds of category pages.